# How to troubleshoot huge snarl of npm install errors?

Tags: angular, npm-install

I've inherited a big Angular project that is very difficult to run `npm install` on. About 3 years ago I somehow managed to make it work on my machine, but unfortunately I didn't take notes on what the magic incantation ended up being.

Now I have a new computer and am trying to get it set up again. As before, it's throwing reams of errors. Any ideas where to start debugging? Here's a full output log from `npm install`:

https://gist.github.com/peterromero/ced9f659e6104729bacbf201e4423e84

Answer (score 1):

Are you using NVM to manage different Node versions?

Try deleting all the `node_modules` in your proyect, then use `npm cache clean --force` . Finally install again all the dependencies.

If this dependencies were installed with a different node version some of them make a bind to that specific version and need to be re-installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it didn't work and the output is the same.